# Count odd decimal digits as a fraction of total digits in an integer

Tags: assembly, x86-16

> Write an assembly MACRO that takes an integer number as parameter.
> Keep dividing the number by 10 until it reaches zero. Then compute the
> percentage of odd digits in that number. ( Example if num=73458 then
> the percentage is = 3/5=0.6)

my code

```
.model small
.code
.data

x dd 73458
MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX
mov si,offset x
mov ax,[si] 
mov dx,[si+2]
mov cx,0
start:
cmp ax,0
je l2
mov bx,10
div bx
mov dl,al
mov dh,0
mov al,0
mov bl,2
div bl
cmp ah,0
jne l3 
je l4
l4:
mov ax,dx
jmp start
l3:
inc cx 
mov ax,dx
jmp start
l2:
mov dl,'0'
mov ah,2
int 21h
mov dl,','
mov ah,2
int 21h
mov ax,5
mov bh,0
mov bx,cx
div bl
mov dl,ah
mov ah,2
int 21h

end
```

but there are errors on it can you help me to avoid errors

Comment: Please tell us what the errors are.

Comment: over flow error

Comment: Keep more careful track of the contents of your registers, and in particular what is in them at each `div` instruction.  Try single-stepping the code in your debugger, and watching the register contents as you go.  Do not forget that `ah` and `al` are part of `ax`, and that writing to either `ah` or `al` modifies `ax`.

Comment: First of all, shouldn't `.code` come after `x dd 73458`? Up to `div bx` looks ok. After that not so much.

Comment: oh yes ,, but the other error is overflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69868059/i-want-to-write-this-code-in-assembly-8086-macro was a better-formatted version of this code (with indenting of code relative to labels), and also with the code in the `.code` section.  It included more of an actual question (how to count total digits), but it's been deleted.  Oh, actually it was using the loop from the answer here, and only that part was indented nicely, so I guess it was a followup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have loaded 73458 into DX:AX. After the first time DIV BX is executed, DX will be the remainder (8) and AX will be the result (7345). You could test if the remainder is odd as follows:

```
  mov bx,10
start:
  div bx
  test dl, 1
  jz l1 ; Bit zero is zero so the digit is even
  inc cx ; Count up odd digit
l1:
  test ax, ax ; If ax is zero, we are done
  jz l2
  xor dx, dx ; Set dx to zero for next divide
  jmp start
```

Comment: can you write it all please?